# HTML DOM and jQuery DOM in one simple line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am working on some code in Javascript using a HTML5 canvas and jQuery. I am using `getElementById` to get the canvas and I'm using `$('canvas')` to get the canvas to use a jQuery function.

The problem is if I use `getElementById` I can't use jQuery on the element and vice versa. Is there a simple line that works with both?

Comment: You can indeed use both `.getElementById()` and jQuery to manipulate the same element.

Comment: You can't use native DOM and jQuery methods on the same object. You either have a jQuery object or a DOM node, and so you need to use the proper methods. You can however extract the DOM node from a jQuery object or drop the DOM node into a new jQuery object.

Comment: You can pass an object to jQuery it doesn't care

Answer (score 1):

jQuery accepts elements as inputs.

```
var element = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
// do stuff with element
var $element = $(element);
// do stuff with $element
```

Answer (score 0):

tcooc's answer is pretty straight forward. Another alternative is:

`var element = $('#id'); // gives you a jQuery object`

You can use `element` for all the jQuery functions. To access the non-jQuery object use `element.get(0).id`